# Send notification from a service running in background after application is closed in Android

Tags: android, notifications

I have made an application it uses a `service` to communicate to a server. The response from the service is used to update the UI. I am using `BroadcastReciever` to do so. When I press the back buton the service continuous to run in the background( I am not running the service on the main thread). Now back button closes my app. now I want to send notification to the user from the service about the response.

Any suggestions?.

Comment: [Notifications](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html)

Answer (score 0):

Notification:

```
  NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

                Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(
                        getApplicationContext());

                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        YourActivity.class);
                intent.setAction("notification");
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                        getApplicationContext(), 0, i    intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

                builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.app_icon)
                        .setContentTitle("Next Appoinment....")
                        .setContentText(response)
                        .setTicker("Ticker")
                        .setLights(0xFFFF0000, 500, 500)
                        // setLights (int argb, int onMs, int offMs)
                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                        .setAutoCancel(true);

                Notification notification = builder.getNotification();
                notificationManager.notify(R.drawable.app_icon,
                        notification);
```

Comment: The approach that you have to take is that you have to maintain boolean variable in sharedPreferences which will tell you the state of application i.e onCreate you fill set that variable to be true and when back button is pressed onDestroy() will be called and on this method you set boolean variable to false. Now when your service returns you have to check that boolean variable. if that value is true you can use broadcast to notify the UI, if variable is false you should use code shared by srikanth gr

Comment: @Rollno1 Where do I place the code suggestted by sriKanth_gr. In the service class or my MainActivity?

Comment: @AbhishekBatra : if i understand your problem correctly. you have to write logic in service.

Comment: do i need to declare `intent.setAction("notification");`in my manifest? like `<action android:name="NOTIFICATION"/>` ?